# VB.NET : input string was not in a correct format

Tags: vb.net

anyone... can you guys help me?
when i'm running the application i get error message

> Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

this is the source error:

> Line 77:         dt = brKendaraan.GetList(txtKeyword.Text.ToString, Convert.ToInt32(ddlMerk.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(ddlPerusahaan.SelectedValue), ddlStatus.SelectedValue.ToString)

and this is my code in aspx.vb

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim brKendaraan As New BL.KendaraanBr
    dt = brKendaraan.GetList(txtKeyword.Text.ToString, Convert.ToInt32(ddlMerk.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(ddlPerusahaan.SelectedValue), ddlStatus.SelectedValue.ToString)

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim report As New ReportDocument()
        report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Kendaraan.rpt"))
        report.SetDataSource(dt)
        CRVKendaraan.ReportSource = report
    End If
```

please help me

Comment: Could you point the line where the exception occurs?

Comment: can you explain what you mean? i'm sorry because really new in vb.net

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are using `Convert.ToInt32()` function, so please make sure you are providing a correct value which is convertible to integer. The error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

means that the parameters is not in a correct format as it should be. Print the `SelectedValue` of your drop downs to dig more on this issue. Perhaps you have problem in data binding.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add open and close parenthesis () in the end of ToString

```
dt = brKendaraan.GetList(txtKeyword.Text.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(ddlMerk.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(ddlPerusahaan.SelectedValue), ddlStatus.SelectedValue.ToString())
```

Comment: uuumm.. nothing happened *sorry for bad grammar

Comment: In VB.NET it is possible to omit parentheses when you call a parameterless function

Answer (score 0):

finally, i tried to add this above my code, and it's work!

```
Dim sKeyword As String = Nothing
    Dim iMerkKendaraan As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing
    Dim iPerusahaan As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing
    Dim bStatus As Nullable(Of Boolean) = Nothing

    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlMerk.SelectedValue)) Then iMerkKendaraan = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMerk.SelectedValue)
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlPerusahaan.SelectedValue)) Then iPerusahaan = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPerusahaan.SelectedValue)
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtKeyword.Text)) Then sKeyword = txtKeyword.Text
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlStatus.SelectedValue)) Then bStatus = ddlStatus.SelectedValue
```

Thanks for your help guys! :D